# Why the callback in mongoose code getting document as null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new Schema({name : String, inventory: {}});
var Character = mongoose.model('Character',schema);
var Frodo = new Character({name: 'Frodo',inventory:{ringOfPower: 1}});
Frodo.save();
Character.findOne({name : 'Frodo'},function(error, character){
    console.log(character);
});
```

I am running it as node optionminimize.js and null is getting logged to the console.It got persisted in mongodb alright, I opened a mongodb shell and ran

```
db.characters.findOne({name:'Frodo'})
```

and get following result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("582fc3bab386f00ed0e7fede"),
        "name" : "Frodo",
        "inventory" : {
                "ringOfPower" : 1
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Why the document parameter in the callback is receiving null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frodo.save()` is a async call so it returns a **Promise**, and you search by `Charachter.findOne` immediately the line after which happens before the `Frodo.save()` promise is resolved.

So, the search must be executed after the character is saved successfully, otherwise it returns null as you mentioned, so your code need to be like this:

```
Frodo.save()
  .then(function() {
    Character.findOne({name : 'Frodo'}, function(error, character) {
        console.log(character);
    });
  })
```